# iOS 11 heic format adds artifacts to masked image

Tags: ios

I'm using the new HEIC format to save a masked image to documents directory.
When comparing to the PNG version of the same masked image I see that some new articafts have been added.

Here is a screenshot of the effected image:
[image: https://imgur.com/a/uVtYh]

Here's a link to working repository showcasing this issue (please view the generated image through the new ios 11 Files app).
https://github.com/vondiplo/heic_wrong_encode

Comment: Why would anyone vote to close this question?

Comment: you need to share some code mate.

Comment: I did, I even linked to a demo project on GitHub :) 
https://github.com/vondiplo/heic_wrong_encode

Comment: I have `findWriterForType:140: unsupported file format 'public.heic'` when running on iOS 11 simulator

Comment: I have tested in on a device.

Answer (score -1):

The mask provided in the git is an 100x98 px, try to use a bigger resolution image as mask that's the reason why there are artifacts, also keep in mind that PNG is uncompressed while hevc/heif is compressed so you can't really compare them.

Edit

Since a better mask won't resolve your problem you'll have to stick with png, artefacts are an known block compression problem as this article describes
http://blog.biamp.com/understanding-video-compression-artifacts/

There is a posible solution to that, but i didn't see documentation from apple how it could be implemented, more details in this link http://www.uta.edu/faculty/krrao/dip/Courses/EE5359/Proposal%20HarshalShah-Interim-deblockingfilter.pdf

Comment: That doesn't help. If you add a mask yourself (as long has it has non binary values) will act the same